# Конфигурация спринг

Tags: java, spring

есть вот такой контекст xml

```
 <bean id="CarName" class="CarName">
    <property name="name" value="Toyota"/>
</bean>
<bean id="Bmw" class="BMW">
    <constructor-arg ref="CarName"/>

</bean>
```

класс Бмв принимает в контструктор обеъкт класса CarName,в котором один сетер.
соответсвенно мы инжектим бин карнейм в конструктор класса бмв.как тоже самое сделать с помощью анотаций ,без xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class CarName {

        @Value(value = "Toyota")
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }


    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component(value = "Bmw")
    public class BMW {

        private String name;

        public BMW(CarName carName){
            this.name = carName.getName();
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }


@SpringBootApplication
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);        
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner initDB(BMW bmw) {
        return (args) -> {
            //bmw - переменая проинициализирована, далее ваш код
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: А что в Main прописать? сейчас у меня там под xml код вот такого типа   `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/context.xml");
        BMW b=context.getBean(BMW.class);
        b.drive();
        b.stop();`

Comment: дополнил ответ...